# NOOBS hangs on rainbow screen, does not boot

Tags: boot, bootloader, pi-4

I've installed NOOBS using the standard instructions included in the zip file,  but every time I insert the SD card, boot hangs on the rainbow screen.

What's funny is that if I flash the card with Raspbian, it works perfectly. What could be causing this?

I'm using a 32GB SD card formatted using the "SD Card Formatter" tool recommended by the documentation, I've got all peripherals like keyboards, mice, and USB drives unplugged, and I'm using NOOBS 3.2. My power supply is the official RPi power supply.

Comment: Sounds like you're following the documentation... can you confirm that you ended up with a FAT32 partition? When you unzipped the NOOBS files did you make sure they all landed in the root, not in some default unzip-subfolder called NOOBS-something?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Pi 4, make sure you connect to exact HDMI0 port as shown in the picture. Otherwise, you will see a static rainbow image on the monitor.
[image]